# Think I may be misunderstanding the Map class methods

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

This keeps giving a null pointer exception... I feel like I'm missing something. This is a `HashMap<Character, Integer>`, by the way. Maybe it's a wrapper/primitive thing? I don't know.

```
int amount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aMap.size(); i++){
        if (!aMap.get(i).equals(null))
            if (aMap.get(i).equals(c))
                amount++;
    }
```

Comment: are you instantiating the `HashMap` using new?

Comment: Looks like the HashMap should be HashMap<Integer,Character> since you are using integer as key and comparing the value with 'c' which I assume is a character?

Comment: @anonymous how can that compile though? I assume it is a typo

Comment: @Saher, I am not sure if it compiles or not. But if it does, it will be due to compiler autoboxing and possibly auto-widening from char to int.

Comment: Your `for` loop suggests that you're trying to treat Map like a List.  Use `Map.keySet()`, `Map.entrySet()`, or `Map.values()` if you want to iterate over all the keys, key-value pairs, or values, respectively.  And when you iterate over an entire collection, it's often preferable to use a foreach loop instead of a for or while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aMap.get(i).equals(null)` throws a NPE if `aMap.get(i)` is null. You have to use `==` to test for reference equality when testing for null:

```
if (aMap.get(i) != null)
```

Comment: @user3353751 - I also suggest you first check if(aMap!=null) then try get/put/other methods on the map..